# PHP: Publicar item API mercadolibre

Tags: php, json, api, mercadolibre

Vengo trabajando con la api de mercadolibre, ahora quería publicar un item (logre hacerlo desde Advance REST client) desde mi aplicacion **PHP**, pero no tengo idea como pasar los parámetros que en Advance REST client. paso escribiendo el json pero así no funciona:

```
$detallesART = array(
'title' => 'item numero 2', 
'category_id'=> 'MLA3530',
'price'=> 10,
'currency_id'=> 'ARS',
'available_quantity'=> 1,
'buying_mode'=> 'buy_it_now',
'listing_type_id'=> 'gold_special',
'condition'=> 'new',
'description'=>  'Item de test - No Ofertar',
'video_id'=> 'YOUTUBE_ID_HERE',
'warranty'=> '12 months',
'pictures' => array('source' => 'http://mla-s2-p.mlstatic.com/968521-MLA20805195516_072016-O.jpg')
);

$crear= $meli->postWithAccessToken('/items', $detallesART);

echo "<hr>".$crear['json']['permalink'];
```

Creo que el conflicto esta en el array en el que envió los datos, no se como enviarlo.

Comment: ¿ Cual es el error que recibes del API ?

Comment: buenas! me dice: "A body is expected. (B)"

Comment: muchas gracias!